# How to add a new column with day of week based on another in dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, nscala-time

I have a field in a data frame currently formatted as a string (mm/dd/yyyy) and I want to create a new column in that data frame with the day of week name (i.e. Thursday) for that field. I've imported

```
import com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports._
```

but am not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Create formatter:

```
val fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

Parse date:

```
val dt = fmt.parseDateTime("09/11/2015")
```

Get a day of the week:

```
dt.toString("EEEEE")
```

Wrap it using `org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf` and you have a complete solution. Still there is no need for that since `HiveContext` already provides all the required UDFs:

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
   Tuple1("08/11/2015"), Tuple1("09/11/2015"), Tuple1("09/12/2015")
)).toDF("date_string")

df.registerTempTable("df")

sqlContext.sql(
  """SELECT date_string,
        from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(date_string,'MM/dd/yyyy'), 'EEEEE') AS dow
      FROM df"""
).show

// +-----------+--------+
// |date_string|     dow|
// +-----------+--------+
// | 08/11/2015| Tuesday|
// | 09/11/2015|  Friday|
// | 09/12/2015|Saturday|
// +-----------+--------+
```

**EDIT**:

Since Spark 1.5 you can use `from_unixtime`, `unix_timestamp` functions directly:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{from_unixtime, unix_timestamp}

df.select(from_unixtime(
  unix_timestamp($"date_string", "MM/dd/yyyy"), "EEEEE").alias("dow"))
```

Comment: where does the 'EEEEE' format come from?  I see the joda-time lib has E for day of week but I'm trying todo day of week as a number.  I'm also trying to figure out why there are 5 E's in that format?

Comment: @jspooner Use `u`. And the source is [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: Everytime I have to search for an equivalent in Java . Why did they have to make three options for languages. It just adds to complications with the answers found on the internet.

Comment: @AkshayHazari Good one but to be honest if you exclude some syntax details Java solution will be identical to Scala.